# Custom ESLint rule that can search the AST tree for nodes that follow the first node

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree, lint

I am trying to write a custom eslint rule that makes sure that for every react context that is created, that a display name is set.

```
const myContext = React.createContext()
myContext.displayName = "myName"
```

It is fairly trivial for me to write a rule that checks the first line and gets the variable name. How would I go about extending that rule to find the second line, and throw an error if it doesn't find it? Ideally, I would like some `visit` function that I can throw a visitor and a node.